# How to link the CSS files with html page in golang

Tags: css, go

what is the appropriate way to link the images and CSS files to html files which used as APIs using golang

I tried the following code but the CSS and images did't render , I used the julienschmidt library for routing the APIs

```golang
    var tpl *template.Template

    func init() {

       tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("*.html"))
    }

    func main(){
       router := httprouter.New()
       router.GET("/", indexPage)
    }

    func indexPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params){

       tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", nil)

    }
```

in index.html I use the link to use external CSS file

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/main.css" />
```

the file structures are

```
/go
 /src
  /github.com
   /My_account
    /WebServerProject
     -main.go
     -index.html
     /public
      /css
       -main.css
      /images
```

Comment: You don't have any route registered to serve the CSS or images - your only route is `/`, which serves the index template. If you want any other path to be handled any other way, you *have to* register the routes you want to serve.

Comment: but if I need to register a route for the CSS and images I need as well to implement a function in route.Handel  route.handle( "path" , func)

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to serve static files on your web server, you can also segment your code into templates in a directory and then serve that directory.

```
r := gin.Default()
files, err := filepath.Glob("./app/templates/*.tmpl")
if err == nil && files != nil {
    r.LoadHTMLGlob("./app/templates/*.tmpl")
}

v1 := r.Group("/v1")
v1.Static("/static", "./_assets/static")
```